# How to map angles from [0..360] to [-180..180]

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I'm drawing a blank at the moment. I need to translate back and forth between "signed" and "unsigned" degrees, [-180..180] and [0..360]

The simple way to go from [-180..180] to [0..360] is

`(d+360) % 360` // (+360 removes ambiguity about the sign in some languages).

How do I do the inverse operation? I can do

`if d<180 d else d-360`

but it looks ugly.

**Edit:**
Here are some example numbers. I want to map this

`[0, 90, 180, 270, 360]`

to this:

`[0, 90, 180, -90,   0]`

**Edit 2:**
OK, brain freeze is over. The answer is

(a+180)%360-180

Comment: Surely you just subtract 180°?

Comment: map(lambda a: a-360, (0, 90, 180, 270, 360)) -> [-360, -270, -180, -90, 0]

I'm looking for [0, 90, 180, -90, 0]

Comment: Subtract 180 doesn't do what I need either: map(lambda a: a-180, (0, 90, 180, 270, 360)) -> [-180, -90, 0, 90, 180]

Comment: Subtract 180 does exactly what you asked for in your question, now you say it doesn't do what you need. What do you need and how doesn't it work for you? Perhaps give an example of a few angles and their translations. Also, you should probably have one end of both intervals open. -180 and 180 both represent the same angle.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk subtract 180 maps 180 to 0 and 0 to 180. It literally rotates the compass 180 degrees, pointing North to South. You can see my two comments above for sample data and how the subtractions you and High Performace Mark suggested produce different results.

Comment: Haha, once you did a couple of examples you figured it out on your own:)

Comment: I simply copied the examples from the second comment to the question, but yes, apparently pasting them was the trick. I thought it would be obvious to everyone here that in either representation of *degrees* 0 (or 360) is North and 180 (or -180) is South and East should stay at 90. I see now that this assumption was unwarranted :=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, brain freeze over the answer is

`(a+180)%360-180`

Answer (score -1):

For mapping a interval to another interval, you can use a linear interpolation
like

```
float map(float n, float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2)
{
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    return y1 + m * (n - x1);
}
```

where x1 <= n <= x2, results a value between y1 and y2

Comment: I don't think this does what I need. It would map 0° to -180°, 180° to 0° and 360° to 180°.